# Как можно скопировать кусок кода html вместе с его стилями?

Tags: html, css

Допустим, я нашел интересно оформленный блок (форма обратной связи).
Как можно скопировать html со всеми стилями?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Есть прекрасное расширение для Chrome [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil) ([исходники](https://github.com/kdzwinel/SnappySnippet)).

1. Выбираем элемент для копирования
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Выделяем элемент в инструментах разработчика
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Переходим на вкладку `SnappySnippet` в инструментах разработчика
   и жмем на кнопку <kbd>Create a snippet from inspected element</kbd>
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Копируем получившуюся разметку и стили, после чего наслаждаемся результатом:

   Слева исходник, справа скопированный элемент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```css
#DIV_1 {
  color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
  height: 198px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 268px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 150px 112.5px;
  transform-origin: 150px 112.5px;
  background: rgb(255, 248, 220) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(224, 220, 191);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px 19.5px;
  outline: rgb(34, 36, 38) none 0px;
  padding: 15px 15px 10px;
}
/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_2 {
  color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
  height: 190px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 268px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 134px 95px;
  transform-origin: 134px 95px;
  border: 0px none rgb(34, 36, 38);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(34, 36, 38) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_2*/

#DIV_3 {
  color: rgb(156, 152, 139);
  height: 14px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 268px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 134px 7px;
  transform-origin: 134px 7px;
  border: 0px none rgb(156, 152, 139);
  font: normal normal bold normal 11px / 14.3px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(156, 152, 139) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_3*/

#HR_4,
#HR_20 {
  color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
  height: 1px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 268px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 134px 0.5px;
  transform-origin: 134px 0.5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(170, 170, 170);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 6.5px 0px 10px;
  outline: rgb(170, 170, 170) none 0px;
}
/*#HR_4, #HR_20*/

#DIV_5,
#DIV_12 {
  color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
  height: 32px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 258px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 134px 16px;
  transform-origin: 134px 16px;
  border: 0px none rgb(34, 36, 38);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px 8px;
  outline: rgb(34, 36, 38) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
/*#DIV_5, #DIV_12*/

#DIV_6,
#DIV_13 {
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130);
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30.9531px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 15.4688px 10px;
  transform-origin: 15.4688px 10px;
  border: 0px none rgb(130, 130, 130);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(130, 130, 130) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_6, #DIV_13*/

#A_7,
#A_14 {
  color: rgb(0, 119, 204);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30.9531px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 15.4688px 10.5px;
  transform-origin: 15.4688px 10.5px;
  border-top: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px -1px;
  outline: rgb(0, 119, 204) none 0px;
}
/*#A_7, #A_14*/

#DIV_8,
#DIV_15 {
  background-position: 0px -4554px;
  color: rgb(0, 119, 204);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 16px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 8px 8px;
  transform-origin: 8px 8px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=65046080049f82845023d54a3c2662c1") no-repeat scroll 0px -4554px / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(0, 119, 204) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_8, #DIV_15*/

#DIV_9,
#DIV_16 {
  color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
  float: left;
  height: 32px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 227.031px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 113.516px 16px;
  transform-origin: 113.516px 16px;
  border: 0px none rgb(34, 36, 38);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(34, 36, 38) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_9, #DIV_16*/

#A_10,
#A_17 {
  color: rgb(0, 119, 204);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 227.031px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 113.516px 16.5px;
  transform-origin: 113.516px 16.5px;
  border-top: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px -1px;
  outline: rgb(0, 119, 204) none 0px;
}
/*#A_10, #A_17*/

#BR_11,
#BR_18,
#BR_26,
#BR_32 {
  clear: both;
  color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 0px none rgb(34, 36, 38);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(34, 36, 38) none 0px;
}
/*#BR_11, #BR_18, #BR_26, #BR_32*/

#DIV_19 {
  color: rgb(156, 152, 139);
  height: 14px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 268px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 134px 7px;
  transform-origin: 134px 7px;
  border: 0px none rgb(156, 152, 139);
  font: normal normal bold normal 11px / 14.3px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px;
  outline: rgb(156, 152, 139) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_19*/

#DIV_21,
#DIV_27 {
  color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
  height: 16px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 258px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 134px 8px;
  transform-origin: 134px 8px;
  border: 0px none rgb(34, 36, 38);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px 8px;
  outline: rgb(34, 36, 38) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
/*#DIV_21, #DIV_27*/

#DIV_22,
#DIV_28 {
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130);
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30.9531px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 15.4688px 8px;
  transform-origin: 15.4688px 8px;
  border: 0px none rgb(130, 130, 130);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(130, 130, 130) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_22, #DIV_28*/

#SPAN_23,
#SPAN_29 {
  color: rgb(130, 130, 130);
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 0px none rgb(130, 130, 130);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(130, 130, 130) none 0px;
}
/*#SPAN_23, #SPAN_29*/

#DIV_24,
#DIV_30 {
  color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
  float: left;
  height: 16px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  width: 227.031px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 113.516px 8px;
  transform-origin: 113.516px 8px;
  border: 0px none rgb(34, 36, 38);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  outline: rgb(34, 36, 38) none 0px;
}
/*#DIV_24, #DIV_30*/

#A_25,
#A_31 {
  color: rgb(0, 119, 204);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 227.031px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  perspective-origin: 113.516px 8.5px;
  transform-origin: 113.516px 8.5px;
  border-top: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 0px none rgb(0, 119, 204);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / 16.9px Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px 0px -1px;
  outline: rgb(0, 119, 204) none 0px;
}
/*#A_25, #A_31*/
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <div id="DIV_2">
    <div id="DIV_3">
      Важное на Мете
    </div>
    <hr id="HR_4" />
    <div id="DIV_5">
      <div id="DIV_6">
        <a href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2603/%d0%96%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow?cb=1" id="A_7"></a>
        <div id="DIV_8">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_9">
        <a href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2603/%d0%96%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow?cb=1" id="A_10">Жизненный цикл вопроса на Stack Overflow</a>
      </div>
      <br id="BR_11" />
    </div>
    <div id="DIV_12">
      <div id="DIV_13">
        <a href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83?cb=1"
        id="A_14"></a>
        <div id="DIV_15">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_16">
        <a href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83?cb=1"
        id="A_17">Поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту</a>
      </div>
      <br id="BR_18" />
    </div>
    <div id="DIV_19">
      Обсуждаемое на Мете
    </div>
    <hr id="HR_20" />
    <div id="DIV_21">
      <div id="DIV_22">
        <span id="SPAN_23">4</span>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_24">
        <a href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2515/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0?cb=1" id="A_25">Почему отклонённая правка?</a>
      </div>
      <br id="BR_26" />
    </div>
    <div id="DIV_27">
      <div id="DIV_28">
        <span id="SPAN_29">6</span>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_30">
        <a href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2560/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0?cb=1" id="A_31">Как реабилитироваться после бана?</a>
      </div>
      <br id="BR_32" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Получившийся код можно сразу отправить на jsFiddle, CodePen или JS Bin.
Точность не 100%-я, но результат все равно хорош.

#### Update:

Удивительно, но IE обошел другие браузеры в этом плане.
Скопированные стили не содержат ничего лишнего.
Вот, как это делается в IE11+:

1. Открываем инструменты разработчика
2. Щелкаем правой кнопкой мыши на нужном элементе
3. Выбираем пункт `Скопировать элемент со стилями`
4. Вставляем в любой редактор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот результат:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
}
.module {
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.module {
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
.community-bulletin.module {
 padding: 15px 15px 10px 15px;
 background-color: #FFF8DC;
 border: 1px solid #E0DCBF;
}
#sidebar {
 position: relative;
}
#sidebar, .sidebar {
 float: right;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0;
 margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
#content {
 min-height: 450px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 width: 1060px;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
#content::after {
 display: table;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
}
#content::after {
 display: table;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
}
.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: left;
 width: 100%;
}
body {
 font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 color: #222426;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 min-width: 1075px;
}
html {
 min-width: 1060px;
}
.related {
 line-height: 1.3;
 font-size: 12px;
}
#sidebar .related, #sidebar .linked {
 font-size: 13px;
}
.community-bulletin.module .bulletin-title {
 color: #777;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #9c988b;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.community-bulletin.module :first-child.bulletin-title {
 margin-top: 0px;
}
hr {
 border: 0;
 color: #aaa;
 background-color: #aaa;
 height: 1px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.community-bulletin.module hr {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.module .spacer {
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.community-bulletin.module .spacer {
 padding: 0 5px;
}
.bulletin-item-type {
 float: left;
 width: 12%;
}
.community-bulletin.module .bulletin-item-type {
 color: #828282;
}
.bulletin-item-content {
 float: left;
 width: 88%;
}
.cbt {
 clear: both;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
a {
 color: #0077cc;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.question-hyperlink {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
}
.answer-hyperlink, .question-hyperlink {
 color: #0077cc;
 line-height: 1.3;
 margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}
.related a {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.community-bulletin.module .question-hyperlink {
 font-weight: normal;
}
#sidebar .related a, #sidebar .linked a {
 font-size: 13px;
}
.favicon {
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
}
.favicon {
 background-color: transparent;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url('../img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=65046080049f82845023d54a3c2662c1');
}
.favicon-rumeta {
 background-position: 0 -4554px;
}
div.favicon {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body class="question-page new-topbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="snippet-hidden" id="content">
      <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Question" itemscope="">
        <div class="show-votes" id="sidebar">
          <div class="module community-bulletin" data-tracker="cb=1">
            <div class="related">
              <div class="bulletin-title">
                Важное на Мете
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="spacer">
                <div class="bulletin-item-type">
                  <a class="question-hyperlink" href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2603/%d0%96%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow?cb=1">
                    <div title="Stack Overflow на русском Meta" class="favicon favicon-rumeta"></div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="bulletin-item-content">
                  <a class="question-hyperlink" href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2603/%d0%96%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow?cb=1">Жизненный цикл вопроса на Stack Overflow</a>
                </div>
                <br class="cbt">
              </div>
              <div class="spacer">
                <div class="bulletin-item-type">
                  <a class="question-hyperlink" href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83?cb=1">
                    <div title="Stack Overflow на русском Meta" class="favicon favicon-rumeta"></div>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="bulletin-item-content">
                  <a class="question-hyperlink" href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83?cb=1">Поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту</a>
                </div>
                <br class="cbt">
              </div>
              <div class="bulletin-title">
                Обсуждаемое на Мете
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="spacer">
                <div class="bulletin-item-type">
                  <span title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">4</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bulletin-item-content">
                  <a class="question-hyperlink" href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2515/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0?cb=1">Почему отклонённая правка?</a>
                </div>
                <br class="cbt">
              </div>
              <div class="spacer">
                <div class="bulletin-item-type">
                  <span title="Vote score (upvotes - downvotes)">6</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bulletin-item-content">
                  <a class="question-hyperlink" href="http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2560/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0?cb=1">Как реабилитироваться после бана?</a>
                </div>
                <br class="cbt">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Чтобы увидеть результат в сниппете его необходимо прокрутить вправо до упора.
Единственная проблема: путь к картинке. Если его исправить, то получается следующее:

Слева исходник, справа скопированный элемент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнительно почитайте вот этот вопрос на SO:
[Tools to selectively copy HTML+CSS+JS from existing sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911338/tools-to-selectively-copy-htmlcssjs-from-existing-sites)

Comment: @duddeniska, я добавил вариант с чистым копированием стилей через IE. Предпочтительнее использовать его. По поводу расширений, то практически ничего в веб-разработке не использую. Изредка только: `Visual Event`, `CSS Digg` и `CSSViewer`.

Comment: 2023г. тема работает. Мало того, если у вас установка расширений в хроме заблокирована корп. политикой, то SnappySnippet можно установить в браузере Iron (клон Хрома): https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/iron_portable